# Onserverclick não está a correr

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

Estou a tentar criar botões dinâmico para apagar utilizadores de uma base de dados mas o onserverclick simplesmente não corre a função.

Este é o meu código até agora:

```
yourHTMLstring += "<td>" + dt.Rows[i]["NivelAcesso"] + "<button id='"+idx+ "' type='submit' runat='server' onserverclick='deleteRow' class='btn btn-light float-right'><i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></i></button></td>";
```

Esta é a função:

```
protected void deleteRow(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Button button = (Button)sender;
        string buttonId = button.ID;

        SQL _sql = new SQL();

        _sql.DeleteUtilizadores(Convert.ToInt32(buttonId));
    }
```

Comment: Torne o evento publico: `public void deleteRow(object sender, EventArgs e)`

Comment: Continua sem correr o evento

Comment: Tenta prefixar o botão: `<asp:button`.... é só um dois pontos

Comment: Não resolveu, já tentei mudar o nome do evento e também continua sem funcionar

Comment: Só para testar, passa o evento para o OnClick.

Comment: Não resolveu, não entendo o porquê de isto não correr o event, supostamente está tudo para que o event corra devidamente.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93427/discussion-between-afonso-and-augusto-vasques).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que o bind do `onserverclick` funcione ele precisa ser declarado fisicamente no seu aspx. Isso porque no evento de renderização e antes do `Page_load` o ASP.Net fará um parse so seu conteúdo e substituirá o seu `onserverclick='deleteRow'` por uma chamada javascript responsável pelo `PostBack` ao servidor, no evento de `click` do elemento.

Veja o exemplo abaixo onde o controle foi adicionado na `Default.aspx`:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication.Form._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <button id='lbotao' type='submit' runat='server' onserverclick='deleteRow' class='btn btn-light float-right'><i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></i>teste</button>

</asp:Content>
```

Agora veja como o componente é renderizado no browser:

```
<button onclick="__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$lbotao','')" id="MainContent_lbotao" type="submit" class="btn btn-light float-right"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
```

Como você está adicionando o controle como uma string html essa conversão não será realizada e você acabará com uma transcrição simples do que você declarou.

```
<button id="lbotao" type="submit" runat="server" onserverclick="deleteRow" class="btn btn-light float-right"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
```

Comment: @Afonso, entendeu o motivo?

Comment: Então como faço para resolver isso? Desculpa se não entendi muito bem, ainda estou a aprender e não sei muitas coisas, obrigado na mesma

Comment: Apresente o resto do código na sua pergunta, se você deseja manipular elementos da tela no backend, deve utilizar os componentes apropriados para isso. Pela única linha que você apresentou me parece que deveria ser um `GridView` ou um `Repeater`...